Inertia Action on Kummer Sheaves
In 7.0.2 of Katz's book "Gauss Sums, Kloosterman Sums, and Monodromy Groups", Katz states the following (when $x=0$).
Let $\chi:\mathbb{F}_q^\times\to\mathbb{Q}_\ell^\times$ be a multiplicative character and consider the associated sheaf $\mathcal{L}_\chi$ on $\mathbb{G}_\mathbb{m}$ over $\mathbb{F}_q.$ Then, these $\mathcal{L}_\chi$ when restricted as a representation of the inertia group $I_0$ are precisely the $\mathbb{Q}_\ell$-valued characters of $I_0$ of order dividing $q-1$ and every tame character of $I_0$ arises in this way up to extending $\mathbb{F}_q$ or $\mathbb{Q}_\ell.$
I searched but could not really find a reference for this fact. Furthermore, if I understand correctly, it seems that when $p=\text{char}(\mathbb{F}_q),$ we have $I_0^{\text{tame}}\cong \prod\limits_{l\neq p}\mathbb{Z}_l(1).$ I was wondering if there is  a reference that explicitly explains what the action of inertia is, hopefully with a proof.

The sheaf $\mathcal L_\chi$ arises from a homomorphism $\pi_1( \mathbb G_m) \to \mathbb F_q^\times$ composed with a character $\chi \colon \mathbb F_q^\times \to \mathbb Q_\ell^\times$.
So to check the claim that these $\mathcal L_\chi$ when restricted to $I_0$ are precisely the $\mathbb Q_\ell$-valued characters of $I_0$ of order dividing $q-1$, it suffices to check that every character of $I_0$ of order dividing $q-1$ factors through $I_0 \to \pi_1(\mathbb G_m) \to \mathbb F_q^\times$.
From your description of $I_0$, we see that $I_0$ is procyclic, so every character of $I_0$ of order dividing $q-1$ factors through the unique cyclic quotient of $I_0$ of order dividing $q-1$. So it suffices to check that $I_0 \to \pi_1(\mathbb G_m) \to \mathbb F_q^\times$ is the unique cyclic quotient of $I_0$ of order $q-1$, or equivalently that $I_0 \to \pi_1(\mathbb G_m) \to \mathbb F_q^\times$ is surjective.
Now the homomorphism $\pi_1(\mathbb G_m) \to \mathbb F_q^\times$ arises from the covering with equation $y^{q-1}=x$. It suffices to check this covering is totally ramified at $0$. But this is clear since the uniformizer $y$ of the covering has valuation $1/(q-1)$ and hence the ramification index is $1/(q-1)$ and the covering is totally ramified.
The claim that every tame character arises this way after extending $\mathbb F_q$ and $\mathbb Q_\ell$ is clear, since every tame character has image of order prime to $p$ and thus dividing $q-1$ for some $q$.

thank you for the answer. I have a silly question. Did you mean that $I_0$ is procyclic or am I misunderstanding?

@HasanSaad Yes, that's what I meant.
